# Sqlite: Count over multiple colums and group by entries

Tags: sql, sqlite

given a sqlite table structure as follows

`id tag1 tag2 tag3
1  foo  bar  baz
2  foo  baz  moo
3  baz  woo  bar 
4  bar  foo
5  foo`

What I want is to count the occurrences of each tag independent of its column.

How could I query the tags over all tag-fields and group them?

What I want is something like

`foo: 4
bar: 3
baz: 3
moo: 1
woo: 1`

I have no clue how I could query over all tag-fields.

`SELECT (tag1,tag2,tag3) as tag, COUNT(id) AS amount FROM tbl GROUP BY tag` obviously didn't work out.. :/

I read about CONCAT, GROUP_CONCAT, SELECT DISTINCT, ... but none of them seems to be what I am looking for.

I do not even know what to search for / how to describe what I want generally so my research leads nowhere.

Anyone who can help? Would be great! Thx in advance

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Use `union all` and `group by`:

```
select tag, count(*)
from ((select tag1 as tag from tbl) union all
      (select tag2 as tag from tbl) union all
      (select tag3 as tag from tbl) 
     ) t
where tag is not null
group by tag
order by count(*) desc;
```

Note:  You should really revisit your data structure.  Typically having multiple columns with the same type of value is not the best structure.  You probably want another table with one row per id/tag:

```
id    tag
 1    foo
 1    bar
 1    baz
 . . .
```

Comment: So where do I set which table should be queried? My table is `tbl`, I tried to replace the `t` with `tbl` but that does not work.Regarding your note: doesn't that mean I'd have 3 rows per id each holding one tagname? Why is three rows with one tag better than one row with three tags? Don't know much about best practices regarding db data structure :)

Comment: @LisaHaase . . . You set the table in the `from` clause.  I replaced `t` with `tbl` to make that clearer.